# Onlyoffice Docs Community Server web interface

Tags: self-hosting

I have Onlyoffice Docs installed in an LXC container and I can access it just fine from my self hosted Nextcloud instance.

Is there an interface that provides direct web access to the Onlyoffice docs server that would allow me to have web based access to the onlyoffice editors without having to use them from Nextcloud?

I found a reference to Onlyoffice web-apps as being a front end to Onlyoffice Docs but I can't find any information on how to install it.

This is just for my homelab, but I often like to edit documents remotely.

Comment: Have your reviewed the steps mentioned on Github?  https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/server

Comment: Yes, I had read that github document.  I have my Onlyoffice Docs server running and I have it successfully connected to my Nextcloud instance.  The question that I have is it possible to access that Onlyoffice Doc server directly via the web just to edit documents?  The use case might be editing a spreadsheet on a PC with no spreadsheet software loaded.  If I had a way to go to a website and load the spreadsheet from a PC desktop, i could use the OnlyOffice instance to do so.  As it stands now, there is no user facing instance on my Onlyoffice Docs server.